# Smush.It or similar lossless image shrinking with API

Tags: images, file-size

Is there a free service, with an API, that performs lossless image file size reduction?

Currently we use [Smush.it](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/) which isn't perfect (have to resort to command line tools), although its FAQ does suggest that an API is coming (no progress on this in over 2 years).

**EDIT**:

Turns out the Smush.it API is alive and well, just advertised as dead. Sending requests to: `http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/ws.php?img=VALID_IMAGE_URL` (where VALID_IMAGE_URL is, you guessed it, a valid URL of an image) returns a JSON object with a Smush.it address where you can download the newly created image. The JSON object also gives you statistics on the compression available.

Comment: Great that the smush.it API is working. The PunyPNG [comparison of compression results](http://punypng.com/about/comparison) is worth considering, because smush.it doesn't quite perform as well the competition. Hard to complain when it's free, though.

Comment: Now using Smush.it to reduce files below 150kb (if possible) then PunyPNGing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [PunyPNG API](http://punypng.com/api), which supports PNG, jpeg, and gif images.

Comment: The images are around 200-300kb. The API limits it to 150kb or requires payment. As this is for occasional use the pricing scheme isn't ideal.

Comment: @Metalshark Are you sure it's 150kb? It says the maximum is 500kb on the [API](http://punypng.com/api) page: http://bit.ly/podL5B I spent a while looking and that was the only other image compression service with an API that I could find, I'm afraid. Image compression via API is a niche service because it's not too hard to do it on your own server using e.g. [OptiPNG.](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: its only 150kb for the free version (500kb costs $5 per month). Wasn't aware of PunyPNG, so thank you for bringing it to attention. Using Google App Engine so local executables are a no-no.